# Gridview with filter in Header export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp.net gridview with filter on each of the column the Header. If I export it to excel, the cells with the filter(like text box, dropdownlist) also appears in Excel. How can I seperate the filter from the header while exporting to excel?

My Code below:

```
    protected void ExportCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            //To Export all pages
            gvRecipeSetup.AllowPaging = false;
            this.FilterWithPaging();
            gvRecipeSetup.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in gvRecipeSetup.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = gvRecipeSetup.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvRecipeSetup.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = gvRecipeSetup.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = gvRecipeSetup.RowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }
            gvRecipeSetup.RenderControl(hw);
            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solved it myself.
Solution:
To hide gridview controls:
foreach (TableCell cell in gvRecipeSetup.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
cell.FindControl("txtSoftType").Visible = false;
}
For hiding edit delete columns:
this.myGridview.Columns[4].Visible = false;